# Good example of "hubris"

Tags: nouns, word-usage

If a person needs help but will not ask for it because they don't want to need to depend on other people (based on their pride), is the word *hubris* fitting to describe this?

How would you use it in a sentence for this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hubris refers to a belief in one's infallability, or inability to fail, not just pride.

If someone refused help out of a belief in his/her "infallability," that would be hubris.

If someone refused help out of "pride," knowing full well s/he could fail, that would not be hubris.

Comment: +1 for nice distinction between *hubris* and *pride*.

Comment: +1: My answer was incorrect.